# How can I do Autocomplete in Typescript ? Have jquery.d.ts & jquery.autocomplete.d.ts files

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, typescript, jquery-autocomplete

**Hi I a m trying to do ""Autocomplete""" in TypeScript & Jquery.**

```
 this.$("#testAuto").autocomplete({
           source: [ "c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby" ]
           });
```

But the compiler can not find the autocomplete in any of the d.ts files.

```
 **error TS2094: The property 'autocomplete does not exist on value of type 'JQuery'.**
```

I am using Jquery v2.

Please help !!

Comment: Have you added the jQuery interfaces to the TypeScript project? If not, you should, otherwise the compiler won't be instructed on what the jQuery methods would return

Comment: I think I did, my other jquery functions works fine..

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a reference to the autocomplete.d.ts file e.g.:

```
/// <reference path="path/to/your/jquery.autocomplete.d.ts" />
```

Although I suspect that you are using the wrong definition file and should be using this one: https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/jqueryui/jqueryui.d.ts

It contains your required definition:

```
interface JQuery {
    // ...

  autocomplete(): JQuery;
  autocomplete(methodName: string): JQuery;
  autocomplete(methodName: 'close'): void;
  autocomplete(methodName: 'destroy'): void;
  autocomplete(methodName: 'disable'): void;
  autocomplete(methodName: 'enable'): void;
  autocomplete(methodName: 'search', value?: string): void;
  autocomplete(methodName: 'widget'): JQuery;
  autocomplete(options: JQueryUI.AutocompleteOptions): JQuery;
  autocomplete(optionLiteral: string, optionName: string): any;
  autocomplete(optionLiteral: string, options: JQueryUI.AutocompleteOptions): any;
  autocomplete(optionLiteral: string, optionName: string, optionValue: any): JQuery;

    // ... 
}
```

**Update: Quick useful solution** Since you are using the bootstrap version, *remove* the reference to jquery.autocomplete.d.ts and jqueuryUI. And just have the following block before your code:

```
interface JQuery{
   autocomplete(config:{source:string[];});
}
```

Comment: Hi I tired both jqueryUI, and jquery.autocomplete.d.ts....but its no use.... again bootstrap.d.ts is conflicting with jqueryUI

Comment: @user1847624 try the quick solution I posted